# Listen at / failed: DatabaseError: Permission denied

Tags: java, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to retrieve data but it's giving me a permission denied error. I set the paramaters to public view.

```
{
  "rules": {
    "Person":{
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true,
    ".indexOn": "token"
  }
  }
}
```

My database looks like this

```
hello-8d296
 Person
    -KjG44HWo5k4K3Fpaf4o
         nodes: "5,6,1,2,3"
         token: "56561"
```

This is my code

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

                //Getting values to store
                String token = editToken.getText().toString().trim();

                Query query = rootRef.orderByChild("token").equalTo(token, "token");
                query.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {



                    @Override
                    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot snapshot, String previousChildKey) {
                        Person user = snapshot.getValue(Person.class);

                        String demo=user.getNodes();

                        System.out.println("Nodes: " + demo);
                    }

                    //other child functions
                    }
```

Am I going wrong somewhere??

Comment: I've already set my read and write to true

Comment: The rules you shared show that you've given read permission on `/Person`. But you're trying to read from `/`, where you don't have read permission.

Comment: I tried inserting the read and write rules before Person and that didn't work as well

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean there. But if you want to query from `/`, you should grant read permission at `/`.

Comment: I inserted ".read":true and ".write" true right after "rules":{ but that still gives me permission denied.

Comment: That seems unlikely. Can you share the exact published rules that you used for that?

Comment: {
  "rules": {
      ".read": true,
      ".write": true,
    "Person":{
      "$Person": {
    ".indexOn": ["token"]
      }
  }
  }
}

Comment: Problem resolved! I wrote .indexOn right after read and write